# how to replace - &#8232; - in classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I want to replace this **line separator** code into `<br>`
what is the vb code for that `&#8232;` ?

Comment: Your tags are confusing. It can't be asp-classic and vb.net??

Comment: sorry i try to tag visual basic

Comment: @user186585 I've tagged it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ChrW()` function to return Unicode character then `Replace()` to search the string and replace instances of the character.

```
Dim text
text = Replace("Your input input string here", ChrW(8232), "<br />")
```

Comment: 8232 is the *decimal* code for the line separator (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Good spot!